# How do I run or create a single Gradle task to run all subprojects and root in a multi-project build?

Tags: gradle

I have multiple projects configured using build.gradle for each and settings.gradle at the top level.

I want to define or use a single Gradle task that will build all of the subprojects and the root.

How do I run or create a single Gradle task to run all subprojects and root in a multi-project build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what all your projects are.

You can call `gradle(w) build` from the root dir if all your subprojects extend the javaplugin.

Other project types (like the ear plugin) need to be attached to the build task manually. The way I do this is by creating the build task like: `task build` and in the ear project: `build.dependsOn ear`

Comment: Nice and simple.  Thank you :) I was missing **--continue** as in **gradle build --continue** and misinterpreted not running the subprojects tests as a configuration issue.  Simply adding **--continue** was enough to run all tests.  It wouldn't be necessary if all the tests were passing.